# Yii2: Access model value in view

Tags: php, yii2

I have a variable status declared in model. Status is a column in gridview that is populated using this:

```
[
  'attribute' => 'status',
  'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
  'value' => function($model){
       if($model->nginSum != $model->sapValue){
         return 'NOK';
       } else {
          return 'OK';
       }
   },
],
```

I want to count the number os OKs and NOKs to display equal and diferent entries with a counter.

I've tried declaring a function in search model:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}
```

and in view i did this:

```
$equal = 0;
$different = 0;
$stat = new EtuLojaSearch;
if ($stat->getStatus() == 'OK') {
   $equal += 1;
} else {
  $different += 1;
}
```

but it's returning null.

What am i doing wrong?

Edited:
function in model:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    if($this->nginSum != $this->sapValue){
         return 'NOK';
       } else {
          return 'OK';
       }
}
```

In view:

```
$iguais = 0;
$diferentes = 0;
$stat = new EtuLojaSearch;
if ($stat->status == 'OK') {
    $iguais += 1;
} else {
    $diferentes += 1;
}
```

Edit 2:
Status is ot getting bound to model using `getStatus()` function.

[image: status value]

Model

```
class EtuLoja extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $nginSum;
    public $sapValue;
    public $status;
    public $Data_Sap;

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'etu_loja';
}

public function getStatus()
{
    if($this->nginSum != $this->sapValue){
         return 'NOK';
       } else {
          return 'OK';
       }
}
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id_master', 'nginSum', 'sapValue'], 'integer'],
        [['user'], 'required'],
        [['user', 'status'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['Atendedora', 'Loja', 'Obs'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['id_master'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => MasterLoja::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['id_master' => 'id']],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'ID' => 'ETU(Slave)',
        'id_master' => 'Master',
        'master.regiao' => 'Master/Região',
        'user' => 'User',
        'Atendedora' => 'Atendedora',
        'Loja' => 'Loja',
        'Obs' => 'Obs',
        'nginValue' => 'Valor Ngin',
        'status' => 'Estado',
    ];
}

/**
 * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
 */
public function getMaster()
{
    return $this->hasOne(MasterLoja::className(), ['id' => 'id_master']);
}

public function getNginAgentDetail()
{
    return $this->hasMany(NginAgentDetail::className(),['CLIENT_ID' => 'ID']);        
}

public function getSap()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sap::className(),['Criado_por' => 'user']);        
}
```

}

Search Model:

```
class EtuLojaSearch extends EtuLoja
{
    public $regiao;
    public $nginValue;
    public $sapValue;
    public $operationDate;
    public $from_date;
    public $to_date;
    public $Data_Sap;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['ID'], 'integer'],
        [['Atendedora', 'Loja', 'Obs', 'id_master', 'regiao', 'user', 'nginValue', 'sapValue', 'operationDate', 'status', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'Data_Sap'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function scenarios()
{
    // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
    return Model::scenarios();
}

/**
 * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
 *
 * @param array $params
 *
 * @return ActiveDataProvider
 */
public function search($params)
{
    $query = EtuLoja::find();

    // add conditions that should always apply here
    $query->joinWith('master');
    // $query->joinWith('nginAgentDetail');
    // $query->joinWith('sap');

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['Data_Sap'] = [
        'asc' => ['Data_Sap' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['Data_Sap' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['regiao'] = [
        // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
        // in my case they are prefixed with "tbl_"
        'asc' => ['master_loja.regiao' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['master_loja.regiao' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    $this->load($params);

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'etu_loja.ID' => $this->ID,
        // 'id_master' => $this->id_master,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Atendedora', $this->Atendedora])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Loja', $this->Loja])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'Obs', $this->Obs])
        ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'user', $this->user]);

        if ($this->status === 'OK') {
            $query->andWhere('nginSum = sapValue');
        } elseif ($this->status === 'NOK') {
            $query->andWhere('nginSum <> sapValue');
        }

    if(" " !== $this->operationDate) {
        $query->andFilterWhere(['master_loja.regiao'=>$this->regiao]);
    }
 return $dataProvider;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your `getStatus` method with following.

```
public function getStatus()
{
    if($this->nginSum != $this->sapValue){
         return 'NOK';
       } else {
          return 'OK';
       }
}
```

It will bind value (OK, NOK) with status attribute when active record is fetched and later on you can use that value in whatever way you wish eg `$model->status`. With this approach, your attribute rendering code will be like following.

```
[
  'attribute' => 'status',
  'contentOptions' => ['class' => 'text-center'],
  'value' => function($model){
       return $model->status;
   },
],
```

But to count different values for status, you'll have to loop through all models i-e

```
$equal = 0;
$different = 0;
foreach($dataProvider->getModels() as $item){
    if ($item->status == 'OK') {
       $equal += 1;
    } else {
       $different += 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: I changed the function and in view i did this(check edited question). But still not counting the number of OKs and NOKs. Am i missing something?

Comment: I did a var_dump($stat->status) and it printed null.

Comment: status is comming null from model. Check image in edited question. Seems (OK, NOK) is not being bound to status.

Status is not a table column. I created it as a custom column to add to gridview. I add value to status column in view